# What's wrong with my AJAX contact form? (php mail())

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

I`ve created my first ajax contact using jQuery and PHP form but it doesn't seem to work.

My jQuery code:

```
var dataString = 'address=' + address + '&title=' + title + '&name=' + name + '&mail=' + mail + '&message=' + message;
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sendmail.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function () {
        alert(dataString);
        jQuery('#ok').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
    }
});
return false;
```

Comment - I`m using alert to display the data string and it shows exactly my string, additionally this script always succeeds and displays "Contact Form Submitted".

Now the sendmail.php part (I believe something is wrong in here):

```
// getting variables from form

$emailTo = trim($_POST['address']);
$subject = trim($_POST['title']);;
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$emailFrom = trim($_POST['mail']);
$message = $_POST['message'];

// prepare email body text

$Body = "You have a message from: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= $message;

// send prepared message

$sent = mail($emailTo, $subject, $Body);

//callback for jQuery AJAX

if ($sent){
  echo '';
}
else{}
```

Any ideas? I know I'm not trimming my $message, I will, but I'm sending just one-word testing mails.

All variables come from HTML form and are registered in jQuery script this way -  var address = $("#cmail-address").val(); . Anyways that has nothing to do with my problem since I'm getting good callback.

And by the way my server allows to send messages and other scripts work just fine.

Comment: where are the variables on your first line coming from?

Comment: From an HTML form, as I mentioned above I'm getting alert with string like ?address=something&?title=something&(...) so that's not the point I believe?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but it might be clearer to list your data using an object literal like { address: address, title: title }.

Comment: Have you tested it with no AJAX enabled, plain PHP? Does it work that way?

Comment: You need to explain exactly what "doesn't seem to work" means. Your email won't send? Incidentally, you can get all values of a form into a string using: `$('#form-id').serialize();` instead of building `dataString` manually.

Comment: I'm getting AJAX  success but mails won't send.

Comment: It's possible that there is a problem while sending the mail. `mail()`  will return `true` if it succeeded to pass the job to mailserver. If mail server fails to send it, you won't get an error about that from PHP. Try looking up mail server logs if it's possible and see what's the problem. I recently had similar issue with `mail()`, where it returned true, but didn't send the mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback function should have something to do with the output from the PHP file.  You are just alerting the same string in your javascript scope.

```
    success: function(dataOut) {  
        alert(dataOut);    
        jQuery('#ok').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
}
```

Of course, you need the PHP to echo something.  Could be as simple as "sent" or "not sent" until you refine stuff later, or it could be exactly the message you want to display.  Also echo SOMETHING before you attempt to send the mail.  It could help identify that the problem is with actually sending the mail and not your use of ajax.

As one commenter mentioned - strings like "?a=1&b=2&c=3" might work for POST, but name/value pairs {a: "cat", b: "dog"} is probably the better way to go.  Strings like that are GET's style, which is probably why someone else confused their answer.

I'd also recommend jQuery's post function.  $.post and $.get are simpler and cover 90% of typical ajax uses (including yours!).  $.ajax is pretty much for oddball special cases

```
$.post("sendmail.php", 
       {address: address, title: title, name: name...}, 
       function(d) {alert(d); $("#ok").html("<h2>" + d + "</h2>");});
```

These last few things are recommendations, they are not likely the cause of your problem, but might make it easier to find that cause.

What IS it that doesn't work?  Your PHP is reached but the email doesn't send at all?

Comment: If you can confirm what I'm suggesting, then you have isolated that the problem is with sending the mail and not with your use of ajax.  Then maybe you should read up on PHP's mail function and, if need be, ask a question specifically about PHP's mail (not about ajax).

Comment: Working on it. At this moment I've switched to $.post and still fighting.

Comment: Af, I don't know why but using your method I'm getting empty alerts all the time. So there's no data sent to PHP script. Af.

Comment: thats probably a good idea, but i really don't think your ajax is the problem.  echo out something EARLY on in the php.  if it comes out correctly, the problem is most likely with, and only with, the mail function

Comment: Have you put anything in your echo's or is it still just a blank space?

Comment: Oh, thank you! So I know what's the problem. But I have another one. How to grab my data then? I'm using something like: var address = jQuery("#contact-form-address-input").val(); (the input really exists and there are no typos etc.). But I'm sending nothing as we found.

Comment: are you still doing the dataString thing or did you switch to the name/value pairs?

Comment: as far as i know we did not confirm that you are sending nothing.  we confirmed that you output only a blank space.  put echo_r($_POST) to get a full view of post array

Comment: I figured it out, man I love you! It finally works! Hoaaah :)

Answer (score 0):

this might be a bit of a shot in the dark - but have you tried sending to other email addresses ?  PHP send mail uses the headers of the server sending the mesage (apache for example).  So when you click "SEND" the mail() function attaches an "x-sender: apache" message.

SOme mail servers don't accept mail from servers that have not been authenticated.

When I'm developing locally - I try sending mail to my gmail and it works, using our company's email gets sent down a black hole.

EDIT - oh sorry - you've said that.  Try echoing the $_REQUEST to make sure you're sending all the variables correctly. put a print_r($_REQUEST); die(); in send_mail.php then observe the results.

OH!  by the way.  switch your

```
$_POST
```

to

```
$_REQUEST
```

I've had that problem before.  Like the down voted answer below, you might not actually be sending POST variables because you're passing the params in with a GET format.

```
 $emailTo = trim($_REQUEST['address']);
 $subject = trim($_REQUEST['title']);;
 $name = trim($_REQUEST['name']);
 $emailFrom = trim($_REQUEST['mail']);
 $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
```

also try

```
 print_r($_REQUEST); die();
```

to see that it's getting passed in.

EDIT2:

As per your comment, see this image for how you'd use firebug
[image]

Comment: How can this file print antyhing with ajax? I mean after submitting my form I'm not redirected to this file so I'm getting no output and I'm unable to see "print_R($_REQUEST) I guess.

Comment: do you have the FireBug addon?  I highly reccomend you install it.  Open FB, switch to the NET tab and click your button.  From there you will be able to read the post and response headers of your request.  You'll be able to see what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

You r using $_POST variables, but send them with GET method..

Comment: Changing $_POST to $_GET doesn't help.

Comment: The data is in $_POST as shown by the `jQuery.ajax` call in the question