# AJAX Contact form - not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've created a simple AJAX, Jquery, PHP contact form on my website with inputs: Name, Email and Message. The problem is that when you write an actual email into the email field the message never comes to my inbox. It works only when the Email input field contains 1 word with no @ sign.

My HTML:

```
<p class="form">Name</p>
<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
<p class="form">Email</p>
<input id="userEmail" type="email" name="userEmail">
<p class="form">Message</p>
<textarea id="msg" name="msg"></textarea><button onClick="sendContact();"></button>
```

My JavaScript:

```
function sendContact() {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "contact_me.php",
        data:'userName='+$("#userName").val()+'&userEmail='+
        $("#userEmail").val()+'&msg='+
        $("#msg").val(),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(){
            sendSuccess();
        },
        error:function (){}
    });
};
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
$to = "dusset@gmail.com";
$from = $_POST['userEmail'];
$name = $_POST['userName'];
$subject = $name . "has sent you a message from .design";
$message = $name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['msg'];
$headers = "From:" . $from;

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);?>
```

Any idea what could be the problem, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with my AJAX contact form? (php mail())](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260455/whats-wrong-with-my-ajax-contact-form-php-mail)

Comment: Checked that article, none of it seems to have solved my issue.

Comment: Please check the link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail

Comment: Could it be due to the fact that you're trying to spoof the from address?

Comment: Did you try echo or error_log the user email to see what you get if a @ is included?  You may have to encode it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php mail() not sending headers when using phonegap and ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006908/php-mail-not-sending-headers-when-using-phonegap-and-ajax)

Comment: @Taplar - I did and it is included, I've also tried doing simply `$headers = "From: email@example.com"` but then it didn't work either, but with `$headers = "From: test"` it works. Basically as soon as the @ is involved it stops working.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing how you pass the *data* to Ajax. An example:

```js
function sendContact() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "contact_me.php",
        data: { userName: $("#userName").val(), userEmail: $("#userEmail").val(), msg:  $("#msg").val()},
        type: "POST",
        success:function(){
            sendSuccess();
        },
        error:function (){}
    });
};
```

Comment: This will correctly encode post values, which was the original issue. `data` should be object, string or array and `it is converted to a query string, if not already a string`.